# Method of data collection

Tags: sentiment-analysis

I am an undergraduate that is currently working on a project in which I need to collect reviews and comments about mobile phones across several platforms and analyse the data to see if the sentiments and reviews have direct impact on the sales of the mobile. My problem is the best method to get this data from sites like GSM arena and the rest of them.